# NullPointerException from MongoQueryCreator with Spring Data MongoDB query using IgnoreCase

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have created a demonstration of a NullPointerException from a Spring Data MongoDB query using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb [here](https://github.com/EdwardPrentice/gs-accessing-data-mongodb/commit/f2aec618829c958e4afb2523cc68ec18a59d71e3).

The NPE is thrown when invoking a spring jpa method on a MongoRepository that uses IgnoreCase and a null is passed in. From the linked code:

```
repository.findByFirstNameIgnoreCase(null);
```

will throw a NullPointerException, where as

```
repository.findByFirstName(null);
```

returns null.

So, how can I have a case insensitive search when using a MongoRepository where I can't (easily) guarantee non-null arguments?

Bonus question, if this isn't by design, how can I help fix this? Can I raise this on the Spring JIRA?

Edit: Confirmed issue, [ticket being worked on](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1608)

Comment: Spring-Data-MongoDB does NOT USE THE JPA API

Comment: @Neil Thanks for your constructive comment, it reflects really well upon you.

Answer (score 0):

[PR fixing the issue in Spring Data MongoDB merged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/439#issuecomment-279322343)

A workaround might be

```
repository.findByFirstNameIgnoreCase(nonNull(arg) ? arg : "");
```

to guard against the null case until the fix is released.